# Wiring a while loop with a continue option in java

Tags: java, while-loop, validation

I am working on a loan calculator with data validation.  I have written everything and good to go.  The only thing I cannot figure out is how to write a while loop in where the user is asked "Continue y/n?: " and then have the program continue ONLY when the user types y/Y and the program ENDS ONLY when the user types n/N, any other input should give an error message like "Invalid, you can only enter Y or N".  So if the user enters "x" it should display the error message.

I have tried else if clauses, I have also tried to validate data with the methods I used in the rest of the program but I simply don't know how to validate strings. I can only do it with primitive data types.

This is the only way i know how to write the loop as of now, the problem is it will simply end the program with anything but a Y.

an option for the assignment is to use JOptionPane but I do not know how to incorporate that into the while loop and have it display a yes and a no button.

```
    String choice = "y";

    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

    // code here

    System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.next();
    }
   }
```

Comment: Pseudo code: while var = input not valid, get value.  Afterwards parse valid result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you want two loops: one doing the work and the other one inside prompting for user validation.

```
boolean isContinuing = true;

while (isContinuing) {
    // do work

    boolean inputIsInvalid = true;
    while (inputIsInvalid) {
      System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");

      String choice = sc.next();

      if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)) {
          inputIsInvalid = false;
      }
      else if ("n".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)) {
          inputIsInvalid = false;
          isContinuing = false;
      }
      else {
          System.err.print("Error: Only valid answers are Y/N.");
      }
    }
}
```

Node: I am using boolean variables instead of `break` statements, it makes the code more straightfoward and readable.

Comment: omg, thank you so much you have saved my life sir.  it works flawlessly.  only thing i changed was add ln to System.err.print("...");  just to make it cleaner.

Comment: Thank you! You can also upvote answers (http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up). The good thing is that you can upvote several answers when you can only accept one. And in all fairness, I think all the other answers you got were helpful and would deserve one.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(true) {
    //Do something
    String choice;
    boolean validChoice = false;
    boolean breakLoop = false;
    while(!validChoice) {
        System.out.print("Stay in loop(Y/N)?");
        choice = sc.next();
        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            validChoice = true;
        }
        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            validChoice = true;
            breakLoop = true;
        }
        if(!validChoice) {
            System.out.print("Error! Pick only Y/N");
        }
    }
    if(breakLoop) {
        break;
    }
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Perhaps rewrite `correctChoice` to be `validChoice`?  (Makes more sense to a casual reader of the code...)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
while(true) {
   // do something
   // get user input (Y or N)
   if(input.equals("Y") {
      continue;
   } else if(input.equals("N")) {
      break;
   } else {
       System.out.println("entered option not valid, please use Y or N");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the best way is to introduce an explaining method.

```
while (userWantsToContinue()) {
    // do another round
}
```

And ideally you would even make this a method on an interface that is a UI abstraction :

```
while (user.wantsToContinue()) {
    // do another round
}
```

decoupling the behavior from the UI implementation.